# Is it possible to use h2o decision tree on a dataframe where one column is a list?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree, h2o

I currently have a `df` with both numerical and categorical values. The issue is that one of the columns has a list of categorical values:
`Colors: [[red,blue,green],[red,black]...]`

I tried converting the `df` into a `h2o df` with:
`#convert df to h2o frame`
`data = h2o.H2OFrame(pantheon_data)`

But got the following error:
`` ValueError: `python_obj` is not a list of flat lists! ``

Is there a way to keep the column "Colors" and to simply flatten the list somehow to just have the values separated with coma? and if it is possible, will the algorithm work? If it's not possible, what else can I do?

Answer (score -1):

```
def listToString(lis):
    return ",".join(lis)

df["Colors"] = df['Colors'].apply(listToString)
```

This will convert `[red,blue,green]` to `red,blue,green` i.e. a string.

Comment: The problem with that is that the algorithm then picks 'red, blue, green' as one string rather than 3 distinct colors. Meaning, if one cell is 'red, blue, green' and the other cell has 'blue, green, red' they will be looked at as they are not the same.

Comment: yes, they will not be same. If you want the model to treat them same then you can also sort these strings so that same color patterns will always look same, or use encoding to solve the issue.

Comment: I just need a model that differentiate between the different list items. Sorting the list won't make much sense in the case where list1=[blue,red,green], list2=[blue,black,green], since these 2 lists will be looked at as 2 different items rather than understanding that they share 2 similar colors. Using encoding will make the model not as accurate since the dimensionality will exponentially increase as there are many colors. Also, using one-hot-encoding is bad for decision trees from my understanding for other reasons.